# An alternative to `xdotool type`

Tags: command-line, application

Is there an alternative to

```
xdotool type "a string"
```

It will be more useful if it is not an X11  app. Because X11 apps seem to be more vulnerable.

Note: I will not use it in a terminal window. So `echo` is not an alternative to that. `echo` does not type. It just prints something in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I've never even heard of xdotool before now, but according to it's gentoo package:

```
* x11-misc/xdotool
     Homepage:            http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/
     Description:         Simulate keyboard input and mouse activity, move and resize windows
```

it sounds similar to what good old `expect` does, especially if you don't want X11:

```
* dev-tcltk/expect
     Homepage:            http://expect.nist.gov/
     Description:         tool for automating interactive applications
```

Edit: An example on how to use expect can (of course) be found [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458487/how-to-automate-the-testing-of-a-text-based-menu). Others should be available in expect's documentation and probably in the results of [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=expect+tcl).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) has some code examples, too. "typing" is done with the `send` command, while "reading" is done with `expect`.
The [manpage](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) also hase some examples to get you started.

Comment: can you give me an example for `type` option for `expect`.

Comment: edited my answer

Comment: I could not find any command to type. add it if you know.

Comment: that would be great if you add a command to type "hello" for me. the command `send "hello"` does not type.

Comment: Since you were using xdotool, you are in a gui, but it would help to know what distro and desktop environments you are using.

Answer (score 2):

If your desktop environment is Gnome or KDE (not sure if this will work anywhere else - and no idea about Gnome 3), then AutoKey is probably exactly what you're looking for (and a lot more!)

AutoKey does a lot of what `xdotool` does, but lets you configure everything in a GUI. It's a full keyboard/mouse event scripting system with phrases and scripting in Python3. Find info [here](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) with installation instructions [here](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Installing).

Normal output from AutoKey appears to your system as if you typed it on your keyboard, so no API or other changes to your applications are necessary.

In the simplest case, you define a phrase with an abbreviation and, optionally, a hotkey. When you type the abbreviation followed by a trigger character such as `enter` or `tab` (or press the hotkey), the abbreviation is replaced by the text of your phrase. There are a number of additional options controlling exactly how this works.

If you need to get more sophisticated, you can write an AutoKey script.

AutoKey scripts are written in Python3 which means that they are only limited by you coding ability. They can do almost anything (even invoke `xdotool`).

The current version is 0.95. If your package manager has an older version, you would be very much better off using the PPA or installing from source.

Comment: project https://github.com/jmetzmeier/autokey moved to https://github.com/autokey/autokey

Comment: @user3694243 Thanks. I updated the answer to point to our new repo.